# how to make lock in fastapi for work with global variables?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, fastapi

how to make lock in fastapi for work with session data or global variables?

```
@app.get("/article/img/{img}")
async def get_img(request: Request, img:str):
    [there i need lock]
    request.session['img'] += 1
    [there i need unlock]
```

Comment: Since you'll usually run your serverside code in more than one worker (and after a while, server) at a time, you'll probably want to look at something like the Redis lock pattern: https://redis.io/docs/reference/patterns/distributed-locks/ - Internally in Python you could use the async lock functionality (important: not thread safe): https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock